# fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found

Tags: c++, python, компиляция, swig

Хотел вызывать C++ функции через питон, но....это оказалось не таким уж и простым, даже учитывая Swig, столкнулся с рядом раздражающих проблем :(

Не находит Python.h

1. Я установил последнюю версию Питона, даже несколько раз пытался переустанавливать
2. Юзал (с соответствующим путем, найденным с помощью find в терминале)

   ```
   export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
   ```

Ничего из этого не помогает.
Для компиляции использую следующее:

```
gcc -fPIC $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -c swig_wrap.c myModule.cpp
```

Comment: А во что разворачивается `pkg-config --cflags --libs python3`  ?? Если там нет `-I` с указанием пути к заголовкам то наверное и не будет собирать. Ну мне так кажется

Comment: @vegorov, спасибо, вы правы, но странно, что `pkg-config --cflags --libs python3` не работает, смотрел несколько стримов, у людей собиралось)

Comment: @nnuttertools разберитесь как взаимодействовать с компиляторм! Ничего сдесь странно нет, просто у них этот хэдэр был в системном пути, а у вас нет. И кто вообще учит программирование по стримам?

Comment: @nnuttertools у них наверное пакет для разработчиков стоял, который и заголовки устанавливает. Типа `libpython3-dev`